# java quartz stop schedule after first exception

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz job:

```
public class GlobalIdleMonitorJob extends AbstractJob {

    @Override public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            getJobService().processUserIdle();
        }catch(Exception e){
            getLogger().error("GlobalIdleMonitorJob",e);
        }
    }
}
```

This job runs every X seconds. I want this job to stop after first failure. In other words, if

```
getJobService().processUserIdle();
```

threw an exception, I want this job not run anymore, only after manual restart or web app server restart. Should I throw a special exception in catch block or how to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the setUnscheduleAllTriggers method of JobExecutionException class object to true(true). Refer the below attached example from the official quartz website for you reference.

--[documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example6.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block you can unschedule a job like this:

```
try {
   getJobService().processUserIdle();
} catch(Exception e) {
   scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey) 
   getLogger().error("GlobalIdleMonitorJob",e);
}
```

If you don't have any other trigger or job in your app, you can simply call `scheduler.clear()`, but this could not be a good idea if you are likely to add new jobs or triggers in the future.